# Version conflict when building an Android Project using Eclipse Luna and Gradle (2.1 / 2.3 nightly)

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've checked this pretty well but cannot find a solution to it.

My environment is Eclipse Luna 32bit on Windows 8.1.
I have the latest Android SDK (currently 23.0.5, Oct 14 release)

The problem is when I use gradle 2.3-nightly that build.gradle using android says it requires gradle 2.1:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'SB'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
   > Gradle version 2.1 is required. Current version is 2.3-20141014220018+0000. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\Rookie\DEV\Eclipses\eclipse-jee-luna-android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.1-all.zip
```

but if I use v2.1, Eclipse produces the following error (that goes away with gradle 2.3-nightly; the build is fine when running 'gradle build' on the console)

```
 org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1
 Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle installation 'C:\Users\Rookie\DEV\gradle-2.1'.
```

How can I tell either eclipse to work with 2.1 or the android gradle plugin to work with 2.3-nightly?

for completeness here is the simple gradle build script
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.3'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
buildToolsVersion '21.0.2' 
compileSdkVersion 19

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can tell the Android Gradle plugin to work with 2.3 nightly. Can you provide more information on the Eclipse issue (e.g. how *exactly* you import into Eclipse)? Instead of using the Eclipse Gradle plugin, have you tried `gradlew eclipse` and opening the generated project?

Comment: According to the eclipse installation i'm using the Gradle IDE Plugin
  Gradle IDE 3.6.1.201408250705-RELEASE org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.feature.feature.group Pivotal Software, Inc.

I think using the gradlew eclipse call is not really an option since I'd like to have gradle integration in eclipse. Thanks though for mentioning it, it simplifies updating the classpath when launching the project in debug mode, right?

Comment: If you want to use the STS Gradle plugin, you'll need to find a combination of Gradle/Gradle Android plugin/STS Gradle plugin version that works. Perhaps you can get help from the STS folks.

Comment: I've just run a 'Check for updates', there was a Gradle Plugin update
    Gradle IDE 3.6.2.201410090835-RELEASE
I installed that and the problem went away, my way of using gradle is right-mouse-button on build.gradle and launching the build task.. i'm just starting to learn gradle coming from maven. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Gradle 2.1 with the Eclipse Gradle IDE Plugin works with plugin version 3.6.2 but fails with 3.6.1 (which allows to use Gradle 2.3-nightly), updating the plugin fixed my problem.

Comment: That's one of the things you should try before posting. :-)

Comment: You're right, I just installed 3.6.1 like maybe four days ago and didn't expect it to already have an update that even fixed it :)